# Not seeing my data with @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am doing a tutorial via Udemy and getting stuck with my data not showing up. I can't explain much of this due to my experience level, but pretty sure the problem is with this @RepositoryRestResource and configuration. Nothing is throwing errors, just not seeing my data.

```
package com.luv2code.ecommerce.dao;

import com.luv2code.ecommerce.entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;


@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>
{

}
```

[image: MyDataRestConfig.java]

Comment: What do you mean by not seeing the data? Do you have data in the database? And how does the SQL look like that Hibernate is executing?

Comment: Hi Simon, there is data in the database, and my localhost:8080 looks like this instead of displaying items in the database ```{
  "_embedded" : {
    "product" : [ {
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/product/1"
        },
        "product" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/product/1"
        },
        "category" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/product/1/category"
        }
      }
    }```

Comment: That's correct. Because you are using Spring Data REST and this uses HATEOS. Please read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.5.6/reference/html/#reference